# Get integer value from malformed query string

Tags: php, regex, query-string, text-parsing, url-parsing

I'm looking for an way to parse a substring using PHP, and have come across preg_match however I can't seem to work out the rule that I need.

I am parsing a web page and need to grab a numeric value from the string, the string is like this

```
producturl.php?id=736375493?=tm
```

I need to be able to obtain this part of the string:

736375493

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/id=([0-9]+)\?/', $url, $matches);
```

This is safe for if the format changes. slandau's answer won't work if you ever have any other numbers in the URL.

[php.net/preg-match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this code initially and it did not work so I tweaked it to `preg_match('/id=(.*)\?/', $url, $matches);` and it works perfectly now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 27):

```
<?php
$string = "producturl.php?id=736375493?=tm";
preg_match('~id=(\d+)~', $string, $m );
var_dump($m[1]); // $m[1] is your string
?>
```

Comment: It's in $m[1] because (from the docs): "If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = "producturl.php?id=736375493?=tm";
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $string);
```

Comment: if the string is like `producturl.php?id=736375493?=tm&page=2` your going to end up with an extra 2 in your `$number`.

Comment: Very true, I was under the assumption that all his strings would be in the format he posted.

Comment: Yep this is giving me an extra number in the string, I have just tried this which works to an extent. `preg_match('/id(.*)=', $body, $matches);` but it's still giving me =tm at the end of the number on some lines.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you have a malformed URL query string, so a regex technique is most appropriate.  See [what I mean](https://3v4l.org/7LnFt).

There is no need for capture groups.  Just match `id=` then forget those characters with `\K`, then isolate the following one or more digital characters.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AiEsC))

```
$str = 'producturl.php?id=736375493?=tm';
echo preg_match('~id=\K\d+~', $str, $out) ? $out[0] : 'no match';
```

Output:

```
736375493
```

---

For completeness, there is another way to **scan** the **f**ormatted string and explicitly return an int-typed value. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xbf8j))

```
var_dump(
    sscanf($str, '%*[^?]?id=%d')[0]
);
```

The `%*[^?]` means: greedily match one or more non-question mark characters, but do not capture the substring.  The remainder of the format parameter matches the literal sequence `?id=`, then greedily captures one or more numbers.  The returned value will be cast as an integer because of the `%d` placeholder.