# Extract number part from the email address in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have an email address format like this - st15103@live.tees.ac.uk 
what i want to do is extract the ID part of this email like this - st15103 
How can i do this using PHP string function ?

Comment: This website is not a code writing service.  Please research your problem and post what you have tried including any errors.

Comment: Hello user4317867, i don't know what's your problem. I know that. i'm asking the question because i don't know the solution for it. suddenly i found the solution that's why i posted my finding to the audience.

Comment: I don't have a problem, this website exists for answering errors in programming/scripting.  Not a place to ask "I need to do X" without showing any research effort or code sample of what was tried.  Key point being effort.  I found a duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941832/php-using-regex-to-get-substring-of-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split on `@` and get the first part ?

```
$id = array_shift( explode("@", " - st15103@live.tees.ac.uk") );
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo. I found the solution like this - strtok('st15103@live.tees.ac.uk', '@');

Comment: Simply just select array key. But array_shift sounds good option. +1

Comment: Well, I guess `strtok` works as well, but my limited PHP knowledge is that `explode` is meant for splitting strings by strings, while `split` accepts a regex, and `strtok` creates tokens.

Answer (score 2):

It's Simple explode it.

```
<?php
$id = explode('@',t15103@live.tees.ac.uk)[0];
echo $id;
?>
```

Hope this helps you