# How to split words from the value of input?

Tags: php, json

i have some json values coming from database, i want to split them so later i can use them where i want. 
Here is the json string.

```
$data = {"DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6":"01#ffff000images\/250place.jpg\u00b8"}
```

What i did was :

```
$decode = json_decode($data, true);
$datablock = $decode->DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6;
echo $datablock;
```

it returns the full value, but i want it like, #ffff000 seperate from images/250place.jpg, because #fff is the background color of that block and the other value is image. and also both things are not static. its a submission form. which has hidden values like these. is there a way i can grab them?
Any help will appreciated.!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941832/php-using-regex-to-get-substring-of-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your first line decodes the JSON to an array (using `json_decode()` with `true` as the second parameter), you need to use array notation...

```
$datablock = $decode->DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6;
```

to

```
$datablock = $decode['DATA-block-C5e35a3f127fb6'];
```