# Extract all line in txt with PHP

Tags: php, txt

I have a file with several text.
In this text always exists a line with especific tags like this:

**<cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">c8c453a568280e8edfad6d6cc4121e3ac8ffc6709001b40a24bb4c0cfcdba8ced7a54a164c4c87d4b58a29fb626e9941</cbc:UUID>**

I need to extract the string inside <cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384"></cbc:UUID>

Actually I have:

```
$pg = file_get_contents(pg.txt);
$tag = "<cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">";
$result = strpos($pg, $tag);
```

But this does not bring me the string inside.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `strpos` on `<cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">` might be a half attempt. But then i cant cuss.

Comment: Do you have any code brother?

Comment: the 2nd answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941832/php-using-regex-to-get-substring-of-a-string is good

Comment: Ruperto maybe give author credit on answer in thread since if anyone answer, your reference is no longer the "2nd". .... Just some advice

Comment: Meanwhile current OP shows zero code attempt and a lot of wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function to find your specific tag with any text inside, saving this text, he will be at key 1 of the result array.

```
<?php

$teste = '<cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">c8c453a568280e8edfad6d6cc4121e3ac8ffc6709001b40a24bb4c0cfcdba8ced7a54a164c4c87d4b58a29fb626e9941</cbc:UUID>';

preg_match("/<cbc\:UUID\ schemeName\=\"CUFE\-SHA384\"\>(.*)\<\/cbc\:UUID\>/", $teste, $tag);
$text = $tag[1];
echo $text;
```