# How to import part of the numeric value to wp all import

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

I should import this data  2019-05-28T00: 00: 00.0000000 + 02: 00  but not in full, only the first part should be published, month-day-year, that is 2019-05-28. In short, I should cut off everything that comes after. I can't figure out how to do it if I have to use str_replace, but I don't know how to set it up. Can you tell me the procedure? Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU5Cp.jpg)

Comment: You should use RegEx like this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941925/16560548

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use regex?

For example this really primitive one: `^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)`

https://regexr.com/65seu

This question gives clues on how to do it in PHP:

[PHP Using RegEx to get substring of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941832/php-using-regex-to-get-substring-of-a-string)